# VLC crashes on playing WMV after installing (and removing) FFmpeg

Tags: uninstall, ppa, vlc, ffmpeg

I have Xubuntu 14.04.  I added the `ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg` repo and then installed `ffmpeg` and `frei0r-plugins`.  After doing that VLC started crashing on playing WMV files.  All WMV files cause it to crash, some after about a half second of playback.  As far as I can tell, no other type of file causes VLC to crash.  SMPlayer and mpv both play WMV files fine.  It seems Parole also crashes on WMV files, but I can't guarantee it played them correctly before.  VLC also still crashes when I untick enable video in the options (so it is audio only).

I've already removed both the above packages, and the ppa, as well as VLC.  I've used grep on dpkg to ensure I've uninstalled anything with ffmpeg or vlc in the name.

I then reinstalled VLC and it still crashes on WMV playback.

Does anyone have any ideas of what packages or files I should delete to restore my system to how it was before installing ffmpeg?

Comment: Does VLC also crash in the guest session?  If not, remove everything again, install `gtkorphan` and remove orphan configuration files with that, install VLC again...